# Create logical partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to use unallocated space on disk to create a logical partition. Using Disks or GParted only gives me the option of creating a primary partition.

It looks I need to resize the windows partition and make it extended then create my logical partition inside it. How can I do this without spoiling the bootability of Windows?

[Screenshot for my disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt6Ou.png)

Comment: Since 2012 when Microsoft required Windows 8 install by vendors to be UEFI with gpt partitioning primary, extended & logical partitions became obsolete. Only if still using the 35 year old BIOS boot with MBR partitioning would you still have logical partitions. With gpt you only have one type of partition essentially all primary. You still have the old MBR, but only can add logical partitions "inside" the extended. And you have a primary partition in between the extended & your unallocated. Windows also does not like to be moved, so difficult to reconfigure. Best to have good backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three partition types: primary, extended and logical, each one with their own pros and cons. Basically, you can create up to four primary partitions (if you're using an MBR partition scheme, but let's not focus on that), one being an extended one (some operating systems don't recognize more than one), and inside that extended one, multiple logical ones. You cannot boot up an operating system inside a logical partition, and that's why we put the /boot partition (which hosts grub) inside a primary one (wow, not it all makes sense!).

As you can see, your extended partition is already fully allocated in three logical partitions, and that's why gParted and Disks only give you the option to create a primary partition.

It is reasonably safe to create another primary partition. It won't break your system's boot.

Best regards.